# How to display each X, Y coordinate value in matplotlib python

Tags: python

[image]

I want to display each x,y coordinate value on the Graph shown in the figure. Only markers are added so far, what if I want to display values with each marker or so?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Given the number of annotations, the graph would become unreadable. You will also run into a problem distributing so many annotations although libraries like adjusttext exist that simplify this process. Better approaches would be hovertext or a table below.

Comment: you could use [ax.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html), but with your data the plot will likely be too crowded.